# Django Simple Captcha image size

Tags: python, django, captcha

How can I change captcha image size and text padding in image?

I read [official docs](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html) and havn't found any of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used this app, but I've found in code something:

```
#captcha/views.py

def captcha_image(request, key, scale=1):
    #function goes here
```

So if you call captch_image with additional paramater `scale`, you can change the size.
If you use urls for this app like

```
urlpatterns = patterns('captcha.views',
    url(r'image/(?P<key>\w+)/$', 'captcha_image', name='captcha-image', kwargs={'scale': 1}),
```

You can change `scale` parameter right in the line.

If you want to change proportions of dimensions, I think it is not supported, because

```
#captcha/views.captcha_image
...
size = font.getsize(text)
size = (size[0] * 2, int(size[1] * 1.2))
...
```

They are hardcoded in the function `captcha_image`. But you can replace the font.

Comment: Thanks!
Your advise helps to change size.
But padding is still problem:
http://i.imgur.com/x5lyoUG.png

Comment: Than I think it is not the problem of `captcha_image` but the problem of css you use.

Comment: this is not screensave, but saved image

Answer (score 1):

take a look at https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/blob/master/captcha/views.py

There are two variables `CAPTCHA_IMAGE_SIZE` as well as `CAPTCHA_FONT_SIZE`
Just put into your settings.py e.g.

```
CAPTCHA_IMAGE_SIZE=[200,200]
CAPTCHA_FONT_SIZE=30
```

and you're fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be an option to resize the captcha in your css (e.g. setting width/heigth to 150%)