# Why is Django-Simple-Captcha image distorted?

Tags: python, django, captcha

Please see the related question I posted earlier: [While upgrading python imaging library (PIL), it tells me "JPEG support not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753607/while-upgrading-python-imaging-library-pil-it-tells-me-jpeg-support-not-avai?noredirect=1#comment31101451_20753607)

I have installed Pillow instead of PIL to get the Django-Simple-Captcha to work. The image now displays.
But as you can see at the bottom of this page, it is so badly distorted that it is basically unreadable and useless: http://predictstat.com/accounts/register/

I have no clue why this is happening now, nor how to fix it. Can someone please advise?

Comment: Distortions are supposed to keep bots from "reading" them. However, those settings appear .. extreme.

Comment: It would be *much* easier for humans to process if the image was *larger*. See https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html for how to control rotation, background, noise, post-processing (smoothing), etc. (Although I have no idea how to set the size from that.)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849981/django-simple-captcha-image-size (and the "scale", perhaps - try with like 4x; alternatively, try cranking up the fontsize via the configuration)

Comment: Ok, I manipulated the image so it is somewhat better now: http://predictstat.com/accounts/register/. Larger fonts, better colors, etc. However, if you look closely, it looks like all the letters were cut off below a certain line. Why is this happening?

Comment: Cool, make sure to (self) answer this question with the relevant solution(s) so it will be useful to others later!

Answer (score 1):

The cutoff happens because I'm using Pillow 2.2.2.

Django-simple-captcha seems to not play with that version of Pillow. So I installted Pillow 2.0 and the cut-off problem was solved! See: http://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/pull/50